# Catch time out exception

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0

I am trying to catch if timeout error occurs in Oracle. After googling a lot i did not find any specific fix for it. I have done below

```
 try{}
   catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 01013)
           CatchException(ex);

    }
```

But i am not sure if timeout exception number is 01013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the code is 01013. Please refer the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm#DAFBGECA):

> Default is 0 seconds, which enforces no time limit.
>
> When the specified timeout value expires before a command execution
>   finishes, the command attempts to cancel. If cancellation is
>   successful, **an exception is thrown with the message of ORA-01013**: user
>   requested cancel of current operation. If the command executed in time
>   without any errors, no exceptions are thrown.
>
> In a situation where multiple OracleCommand objects use the same
>   connection, the timeout expiration on one of the OracleCommand objects
>   may terminate any of the executions on the single connection. To make
>   the timeout expiration of a OracleCommand cancel only its own command
>   execution, simply use one OracleCommand for each connection if that
>   OracleCommand sets the CommandTimeout property to a value greater than
>   0.

Comment: @Richa:- Sorry, I missed the oracle part. Yes the error code for oracle is 01013.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are possibly two other error codes which will throw when the `.CommandTimeout` is exceeded. Those are `ORA-00936` and  `ORA-00604`. Found in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/OracleCommandClass.htm#DAFBGECA).

> When the specified timeout value expires before a command execution finishes, the command attempts to cancel. If cancellation is successful, an exception is thrown with the message of **ORA-01013**: user requested cancel of current operation. Other possible exceptions thrown after a command timeout expiration occurs include **ORA-00936** and **ORA-00604**. If the command executed in time without any errors, no exceptions are thrown.

So your code should be:

```
try
{
    // Data Access
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 01013 ||  ex.Number == 00936 || ex.Number == 00604)
        CatchException(ex);
}
```